How to Pass User Input as Command Parameter in DOSBox?
I’m trying to get user input in DOSBox and pass that as a parameter for a command. Batch files seem to struggle when run through DOSBox
I’m using the DOSBox emulator on iOS via the iDOS 3 app. The APP ONLY runs using a DOSBox.conf file, which I can configure to execute commands. For example, I want to run this command for multiplayer games:
IPXNET 0.0.0.0
However, I want the IP address (0.0.0.0 in this case) to be dynamic and accept user input instead of being hardcoded in the configuration file. I tried creating a batch file with the following command to prompt for user input:
SET /P IP_VAR="Insert IP here: "
But the batch doesn’t work when run through DOSBox. I could use the set command in the DOSBox .conf to define environment variables, but I still can’t reference them  with something like IPXNET %IP_VAR%, DOSBox doesn’t resolve %IP_VAR% and treats it as a literal string. Even if I I could reference it, it’s still not input.
Is there a way to:
1.  Prompt for user input in DOSBox with minimal to no batch (it doesn’t seem to work)?
2.  Pass that input as a parameter to a command?
I can get everything done manually, I’m just trying to automate it so I can share with friends. For now I want to find a solution that works for regular DOSBox on Windows, but if there are specific constraints for iDOS, I’d appreciate advice on those as well.
Thanks in advance for your help!

In case somebody's wondering why he doesn't just prompt for input inside DOSBox, it's not that easy. DOS doesn't have a good way to set environment variables from user input.
